# jquery mobile : prevent line break before select button

Tags: jquery-mobile

In the header of a page of my mobile app, I have :

```
    <header data-role="header">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <select name="select-choice-share" id="select-choice-share" class="shareitbutton" data-icon="myapp-shareicon" data-iconpos="notext" onchange="handleSocialShare()">
            <option value="facebook">Share on Facebook</option>
            <option value="twitter">Tweet</option>
            <option value="email">Email</option>
        </select>
      <a href="#creditspage" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Credits</a>
    </header>
```

but the select button is on the next line, whereas I want it on the same line.
I tried a few things, but I can't make it work.
Can you help me find the right CSS?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/kadaj/593Ba/

```
<header data-role="header" class="header">
    <span class="title">title</span>
    <div class="share-it-wrapper">
        <select name="select-choice-share" id="select-choice-share" class="shareitbutton" data-icon="myapp-shareicon" data-iconpos="notext" onchange="handleSocialShare()">
            <option value="facebook">Share on Facebook</option>
            <option value="twitter">Tweet</option>
            <option value="email">Email</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <a href="#creditspage" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Credits</a>
</header>
```

css

```
.header {
    padding: .5em;
}
.title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: .5em;
}
.share-it-wrapper {        
    margin: -2.4em 0 0 3em;
}
```

Comment: thanks @kadaj, I used this: `.share-it-wrapper {        
    margin-top: -3.4em;
    margin-right: 4em;
    float:right;
}` but I'm not sure it is the best thing with JQM to use absolute positionning...isn't there a cleaner solution ? thanks

Comment: Why do you use float? Floating in mobile pages seems to create more problems. Anyway, I am not using absolute positioning. It's relative.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<select data-inline="true" name="select-choice-share" id="select-choice-share" class="ui-btn-left shareitbutton" data-icon="myapp-shareicon" data-iconpos="notext">
            <option value="facebook">Share on Facebook</option>
            <option value="twitter">Tweet</option>
            <option value="email">Email</option>
</select>
```

I added the `data-inline` attribute and the class `ui-btn-left`.

Also you need some CSS as `.ui-select` has by default a `relative` position:

```
.ui-header .ui-select{
    position: absolute;
    top: .3125em;
}
```

Demo [here](http://jsbin.com/ezupob/2).